# Badges should be ordered alphabetically

Tags: feature-request, badges, profile-page

A minor nit, but to satisfy my OCD, could you order the badges on the profile page:

1. alphabetically
2. by badge color, then alphabetically
3. by badge count, then alphabetically, or
4. by badge color, then count, then alphabetically

Unordered, as is seemingly the default now, isn't particularly helpful.

**EDIT**: If, in fact, the badges are listed by date last awarded (seems odd that I would have gotten Editor before getting Critic or Teacher before Autobiographer), this information could be retained in the hover over by appending the last date awarded to the badge description, e.g., *bronze badge: Earned 100 points answering questions in the blah-blah tag. Last awarded Sep 7, '10 at ...*

Comment: CDO = OCD in alphabetic order

Comment: @squillman - Yeah, I know, but I've used that joke too often.

Comment: Never gets old.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Suggested improvements to badges index page](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1980/suggested-improvements-to-badges-index-page)

Answer (score 83, accepted):

I disagree. How about this?

[image]

<sub>(Click for full size.)</sub>

Comment: oh wow that's the best lol I've had in *days*. Thank you Jon Seigel.

Comment: `order by [Tower]` should be an easy enough change :)

Comment: Odd, but that does, in fact, seem to help and satisfies my OCD.  :-)

Comment: This is sick. And wonderful.

Comment: I'm intrigued - how did you do this, and how long did it take?

Comment: Have fun storming *that* castle.

Comment: "Sorry, but the Electorate badge is in another castle."

Comment: hey, where's Mario?

Comment: @Jon: I started with a screenshot of your badge page, then used Paint Shop to arrange them, using [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1939/kbd-elements-are-way-intrusive/1974#1974) as a template (10k only). It took about 2 hours to make from start to finish. And yes, there were *many* badges left over when I was finished. ;)

Comment: Actually, that link is not 10k only. I thought it was a deleted question.

Answer (score 12):

I actually get pretty tired of the rigid, "boxed in" feel of the Stack Overflow design. I was thinking of a more "organic" feel to the sorting of badges:

[image]

Comment: I know that @Jeff likes whitespace, but that's going a little overboard.

Comment: Why not rip off the Google crazy balls logo, replacing the balls with badges.

Comment: Remember "Owner-Draw Controls" ? How about a plugin API to draw yer badges anyway you like?

Comment: How about making them fly around in response to the mouse cursor, like the "Google logo made of circles" did a couple of days ago?

Comment: @Jon - or maybe it could simply show me the one I'm looking for without any input like Google will once they get "prescient search" to work.

Comment: Hey, look it's a tag cloud!

Answer (score 5):

The badges are displayed in order of the date that you earn them.

There is a question/feature request [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16040/please-tidy-how-badges-are-displayed) to get the order changed which by the looks of it has been rejected.  I can't be sure that has been rejected as it hasn't been assigned a moderator only tag.

Maybe a Moderator can confirm?

Comment: Well, [they *will be* soon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63698/rearrange-badges-once-again-on-real-receiving-date). ;)

Comment: @gnostradamus - ha! yes i did see that question earlier.  I was rather hoping no one would mention it.  *brushes offending question under the carpet*

Comment: ...are displayed in order of the date you *most recently* earned them.

Comment: I would have said that too -- even typed it into my question -- but I'm pretty sure I earned Autobiographer before Teacher (like on the first day). Perhaps that only applies to badges after a certain date. Either way, it doesn't really help do anything meaningful with them -- like say find one. Sorted alphabetically with a "last date earned" hover over would be much more useful.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest ordering by badge colour first. Not just ordering, but I think it would also be better to have some sort of separator between the groups of gold, silver and bronze badges.

Otherwise important badges will get diluted in the flood on minor badges.

Can you spot the [Legendary badge](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/146/legendary) in here?

[image]

Comment: "Can you spot the 'legendary' badge in here?" - Yes, and it took all of 1-2 seconds; even at the slightly zoomed out size. I think ordering badges some other way would make sense, I just don't think yours is a good argument for it.

Comment: @Adam: Now find the `[arrays]` bronze badge :) ... Seriously, it requires an O(n) sequential search to verify if a user has a badge or not. That was my argument :) ...

Answer (score 1):

Here's an even *better*, more *dynamic* way of ordering them.

Bookmarklet:

```
javascript:function A(){for(i=0;i-DIL;i++){DIS=DI[i].style;DIS.position="absolute";DIS.left=Math.sin(R*x1+i*x2+x3)*x4+x5+"px";DIS.top=Math.cos(R*y1+i*y2+y3)*y4+y5+"px"}R++}R=0;x1=.1;y1=.05;x2=.25;y2=.24;x3=1.6;y3=.24;x4=300;y4=200;x5=300;y5=200;DI=$(".badge");DIL=DI.length;setInterval("A()",20);void 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Excepting tag badges, all badges are listed in alphabetical order on the [badges tag](https://stackoverflow.com/badges). Now if only [that checkmark linked to the same user specific search as the profile's badge link does](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63962/link-the-checkmark-in-the-badges-list-to-the-users-badge-achievment-search)...