# Link the checkmark in the badges list to the user's badge-achievment search

Tags: feature-request, badges, hyperlinks, accepted-answer

(I mean the the same link that you get for badges from you profile site)

(Trying to assist [Badges should be ordered alphabetically](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63745/badges-should-be-ordered-alphabetically))