# Allow specifying sites for the new tag formatting (at least, to some degree)

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, markdown

The new ability to apply special [formatting](/questions/tagged/formatting) to [tags](/questions/tagged/tags) in [questions](/questions/tagged/questions) and [answers](/questions/tagged/answers) is great! But I'd like to make a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) and hopefully not get shot for this horrendous [abuse](/questions/tagged/abuse).

Can we allow some level of site specification for this? I can see that being able to specify *any* SE site would be problematically annoying. But I think that at least being able to specify, for example, **tags from the parent site when posting on the Meta site** would be useful. On the Meta site for any Stack Exchange site, proper tagging is a very common topic of discussion, and being able to use the new tag formatting will roll right in comfortably. But currently, instead of linking to the tag you actually mean, it'll link to the (typically non-existent) Meta tag.

Comment: Does the phrase `<kbd>` mean anything to you, @Grace?

Comment: @Popular It means that someone *has* to build a castle with this new tag formatting before they take the privilege away!

Comment: @Grace, [way ahead of you](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/264010#264010).

Comment: [It's hard to build a castle when you don't have monospaced blocks to use](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/264033#264033). (Answer since deleted, 'cause I am not trying to get banned.)

Comment: @Pop Gun What would the fun be if it were easy? Besides, the [last castle constructed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63745/badges-should-be-ordered-alphabetically/63816#63816) resulted in Jeff getting [an (old rules) Announcer badge](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/74/announcer?userid=1).

Comment: @Grace, a ban results in fun levels dropping to zero for a day/week/month/year. I am merely maximizing my net fun over the long term.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The new `tag` macro has been changed to refer to the parent site, and an equivalent `meta-tag` has been added for when you wish to refer to a... well, meta tag.

[a-tag-on-mso](/questions/tagged/a-tag-on-mso)
[stackoverflow](/questions/tagged/stackoverflow)

```
[meta-tag:a-tag-on-mso]  
[tag:stackoverflow]
```

This does not apply retroactively, but any post containing the old `tag` syntax will be updated on next edit.  Be aware that the `meta-tag` syntax is only available on MSO and per-site metas, as `tag` continues to point to the current site when used on non-meta sites.

Comment: It would be useful for this answer to be community wiki, so that mere mortals (such as myself) would be able to see the markdown for it.

Comment: @SamB - it is documented [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66965/is-there-some-markup-to-post-tags/69482#69482)

Comment: @Sam: You can always view the revision history of posts, which has links to see the source for each revision.

Comment: @Jon: I can? It's not obvious to me how to do that...

Comment: @Sam: http://<site>/posts/<PostId>/revisions (this works for questions, too). You can get and answer PostId by hovering over the "link" link.

Comment: @Jon: Ah. Excellent UI, that...

Answer (score 16):

<kbd>[discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion)        [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion)        [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion)

             [interview-questions](/questions/tagged/interview-questions) [subjective](/questions/tagged/subjective) [possible-homework](/questions/tagged/possible-homework)

             [ul](/questions/tagged/ul) [http404](/questions/tagged/http404) [compile](/questions/tagged/compile) [set](/questions/tagged/set) [formula](/questions/tagged/formula) [lnk2019](/questions/tagged/lnk2019) [mv](/questions/tagged/mv)

             [virtual](/questions/tagged/virtual) [nsinteger](/questions/tagged/nsinteger) [operator](/questions/tagged/operator) [qlistview](/questions/tagged/qlistview) [binding](/questions/tagged/binding)

             [ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby) [x](/questions/tagged/x)       [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) [python](/questions/tagged/python) [xml](/questions/tagged/xml)       [r](/questions/tagged/r) [perl](/questions/tagged/perl)

             [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) [vb6](/questions/tagged/vb6)       [haskell](/questions/tagged/haskell) [iphoneos](/questions/tagged/iphoneos)       [css](/questions/tagged/css) [f#](/questions/tagged/f%23)

             [java](/questions/tagged/java) [c](/questions/tagged/c)       [php](/questions/tagged/php) [oracle](/questions/tagged/oracle) [sql](/questions/tagged/sql)       [d](/questions/tagged/d) [html](/questions/tagged/html)

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)      [support](/questions/tagged/support)      [support](/questions/tagged/support)      [support](/questions/tagged/support)      [support](/questions/tagged/support)      [bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

[featured](/questions/tagged/featured) [status-reproduced](/questions/tagged/status-reproduced) [status-reproduced](/questions/tagged/status-reproduced) [status-reproduced](/questions/tagged/status-reproduced) [featured](/questions/tagged/featured)

[faq](/questions/tagged/faq) [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) [faq](/questions/tagged/faq)

[featured](/questions/tagged/featured) [status-reproduced](/questions/tagged/status-reproduced) [status-reproduced](/questions/tagged/status-reproduced) [status-reproduced](/questions/tagged/status-reproduced) [featured](/questions/tagged/featured)

[faq](/questions/tagged/faq) [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) [faq](/questions/tagged/faq)

[featured](/questions/tagged/featured) [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned)     [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned) [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) [featured](/questions/tagged/featured)

[faq](/questions/tagged/faq) [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) [status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred)            [status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred) [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) [faq](/questions/tagged/faq)

[featured](/questions/tagged/featured) [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) [featured](/questions/tagged/featured)                [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) [featured](/questions/tagged/featured)

[faq](/questions/tagged/faq) [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review)                [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) [faq](/questions/tagged/faq)

[featured](/questions/tagged/featured) [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) [featured](/questions/tagged/featured)                [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) [featured](/questions/tagged/featured)

[faq](/questions/tagged/faq) [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review)                [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) [faq](/questions/tagged/faq)

[featured](/questions/tagged/featured) [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) [featured](/questions/tagged/featured)                [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) [featured](/questions/tagged/featured)</kbd>

#### [OUR](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1939/kbd-elements-are-way-intrusive/1974#1974) [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [IS IN ANOTHER CASTLE!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1939/kbd-elements-are-way-intrusive/1974#1974)

Comment: [<!-- Don't ban me :) -->](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/89b10477-efee-48e5-8c05-037407142402/view-source)

Comment: Oh noes! It's broken now.

Comment: @Jon: What the... why is `<kbd>` back?

Answer (score 3):

This is going to sound a bit odd.

An easy fix to make these tags more usable is to *only* link to the parent site, or in the context of this question, point there *by default*. This is really just a metadiscussion shortcut (instead of doing the `[tag]` thing), and metadiscussion is almost always in reference to the parent site, not to itself.

In fact, I don't really see the point of even having them enabled on the parent site at all. If a question is a discussion about tags on the site, it's a meta question and should be migrated. (And anyone doing *that* likely won't be savvy enough to use the new syntax anyway.)

In summary, I think the *default* target for the tags should be the parent site. Changing the site target would be a nice ability to have, but we could probably do without it if the tags only ever linked to the parent site.

Comment: Odd, but completely reasonable. The important thing is that `[tag:weapons]` is a whole lot faster to write and a whole lot nicer to read than `[**[weapons]**](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/weapons)` is, especially in retag requests and heavy tag discussions. Other Meta sites won't often need to reference the tags on the Meta sites, as a lot of that kind of tag discussion occurs on this site instead.

Comment: However, I think that the syntax is useful on the parent site, namely in tag wikis. It makes it look much cleaner and more in unison with each other, to be able to refer to other tags quickly like that on the tag wikis. So I'd say we strike middle-ground and have both parent and meta site default to the parent site. For MSO and SO, this just means the site itself due to the lack of per-site-metas for both.

Comment: I agree mostly, but the `[status-***]` tags, `[faq]`, and 4 required meta tags (`[feature-request]` etc) should always link to the meta site.

Comment: @Kenny Don't forget `[featured]`.

Comment: @Grace: Right. There are a set of default tags for every SE 2.0 meta sites e.g. `[community-wiki]`, `[allowed-questions]`, etc. They should point to meta as well.