# The markup [tag:…] should use the style on the parent site

Tags: feature-request, tags, markdown, design

If we use the recently added [`[tag:…]` markup](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69513/allow-specifying-sites-for-the-new-tag-formatting-at-least-to-some-degree/69644#69644) on Meta, the tags are rendered in the style on Meta, but this is counterintuitive because they refer to tags on parent.  Example: [haskell](/questions/tagged/haskell)

The parent tags should be always rendered in the style used for tags on the parent site, even if the markup is used on Meta.

*Added*: I have just noticed that Kevin Montrose [already writes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66965/is-there-some-markup-to-post-tags/69482#69482):

> Note that we aren't pulling in styling from the "parent" site either, though that may change in the future.

So, my request is simple: please do!

Comment: You simply state please do. But why? What value does this add? How would this improve the site in anyway whatsoever? How would you quantify the cost of having a developer spend time to implement this?

Comment: @Diago: I stated the reason in the beginning of this post: “this is counterintuitive because they refer to tags on parent.”

Comment: @Diago: As for the development cost, I do not know.

Comment: How is it counterintuitive? Is that the only real true reason? When posting a question, and mentioning a tag, a consistent look & feel  across all the sites makes more sense. Otherwise it will be confused with the actual tags on the question.

Comment: @Diago: (1) It is better to style the same thing in the same way.  This is why parent tags in Meta posts should be rendered in the same style as parent.  (2) I have no idea what you mean by “it will be confused with the actual tags on the question.”  If anything, rendering [tag:…] on Meta in the parent style will _reduce_ the possible confusion with the actual tags on the question.  But that is not the primary reason for this feature request.

Comment: This is moot now that Meta.SE has no parent site, right?