# SO tag sponsor icons don't show up in tags on MSO

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, advertising

Those of us who enjoy formatting a little too much have really liked the recent introduction of the [tags in posts feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69513/allow-specifying-sites-for-the-new-tag-formatting-at-least-to-some-degree/69644#69644). There's a minor inconsistency with the display of sponsored tags, though.

On SO, the company redgate sponsors the tag [sql-server](/questions/tagged/sql-server). As you can see, here on Meta, the icon doesn't show up in the tag. There's a screenshot of what the icon "should" look like at [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30187/what-does-rg-mean).

I'm guessing this is by-design, actually. If faithful replication was the goal, the tag background color would be SO blue, not Meta gray. But it seemed to be worth reporting just in case.

Comment: I'm kinda torn as to whether or not it *should* show up, but +1 for raising the issue.

Comment: All I've got to say is 'Thank f*** they don't show up on MSO ;b'.  But I've got beef with ads in tags.  See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23955/adobe-sponsored-tags/24121#24121

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, I don't really think its worth the effort.

We don't generally export "ad data" anyway.  For instance, sponsored tags are not reflected as such in the [API](http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/tags?filter=sql-server).