# `[tag:]` should work in comments

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, comments, markdown, tag-links

I think it would be useful if the `[tag:]` tag-linking syntax worked in comments.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`[tag:...]` and `[meta-tag:...]` now work in comments, with the [same semantics as in posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69513/allow-specifying-sites-for-the-new-tag-formatting-at-least-to-some-degree/69644#69644). They are however not styled as tags, but as plain links (with the link text being the tag name); we don't want excessive styling in comments.

Comment: `[meta-tag:fun] [tag:c#]` -> [meta-tag:fun] [tag:c#]

Comment: Bouns +1 for staying sane and rendering them as plain links.

Comment: @TimStone: SANITY IS OVERRATED! ***MUAHAHAHAHAHA***

Comment: Your "sanity" is no match for the [power of jQuery](http://so.mrozekma.com/tags-in-comments.png)

Comment: @Michael: I was wondering how doable that would be—is there a userscript somewhere that does that?

Comment: @Isaac No idea; I just did `$('a[href*="/tagged/"]').addClass('post-tag');`. An actual script should probably put some effort into the URL part

Comment: @Michael: I put a small modicum of effort into it—about 10 minutes' worth—and [here's the result](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/104448), which I've got installed myself, more because I like the tag hover popup than because I want tags styled like tags (though I do like that part, too).

Comment: @balpha - -1 for the comment. [We HATE fun](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/01/stack-overflow-where-we-hate-fun/)

Answer (score 7):

The `[tag:]` syntax generates objects slightly taller than plain text and causes some modest layout artifacts. I suspect these would be pretty distracting in the comments, so I'm not very motivated by this idea.

Comment: Perhaps with the size adjusted to be in scale with comments?  (I hadn't thought of this because it occurred to me on an SE site where tags do not have a surrounding box.)

Comment: Seems like a pretty easily surmounted issue to me. I know you couldn't just slap a CSS border on there and call it good, but it's hardly a difficult problem.