# tags not rendered correctly in comments

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tags, design

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [`[tag:]` should work in comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71998/tag-should-work-in-comments)

See my comment for example.

tags should be rendered like this [tag](/questions/tagged/tag).

Comment: Instead they are rendered like this [tag:tag].

Comment: [meta-tag:status-bydesign]...

Comment: See the [accepted answer of the dupe](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/94180/140951) to see why it's not styled the same in comments.

Comment: http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/104448

Answer (score 1):

Comments are secondary. Displaying a tag as [tag](/questions/tagged/tag) on  a comment just draws more attention to a comment than it should.