# What are tag badges? How do they work?

Tags: support, badges, tag-badges

My question is specifically for badges in a particular tag. I've heard that the rules have been changed.

How and when can one get bronze, silver and gold badges for a specific tag, say [stackexchange](/questions/tagged/stackexchange)?
What are the new rules governing these badges?

[Return to FAQ index](/q/7931)

Answer (score 276, accepted):

### What are tag badges?

Tag badges are, well, *badges* which are awarded to users for achieving a certain score on a specific tag, indicating their knowledge and understanding of that tag.

### What tags are eligible for badges?

A tag must appear on a minimum of 100 questions to be eligible for tag badges.

### How do I earn each type of tag badge?

- **Bronze:** Have a total tag score of 100 across a minimum of 20 answers
- **Silver:** Have a total tag score of 400 on a minimum of 80 answers
- **Gold:** Have a total tag score of 1,000 on a minimum of 200 answers

### What is this tag score you speak of?

A tag score is basically the combined total of all the upvotes (+1) and downvotes (-1) you've accumulated on **answers** under that specific tag (votes on questions do not count). Acceptance of an answer doesn't have any weight in the score. As well, posts that are in community wiki status or that have been deleted do not count towards your tag score. Tag scores are only recalculated once daily, at 03:00 UTC.

### My tag badge can't be revoked, like normal badges, right?

Wrong. Tag badges, unlike normal badges, are automatically revoked upon a tag score recalculation if the tag is no longer eligible to have badges, or you no longer have the required tag score or minimum valid answer count for the badge.

### Do tag badges do anything besides allowing me to show off?

The gold version of each badge gives you certain [close rights](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231212) for questions marked with that tag:

> - You can instantly close as a duplicate any question that was    originally asked with a tag you have a gold badge for.
> - You can instantly reopen any question closed as a duplicate that was    originally asked with a tag you have a gold badge for.
> - You can only close or reopen a given question once (this hasn't    changed).

Comment: As total score is now calculated as the difference between upvotes and downvotes, shouldn't the tag badge description template be changed to reflect this? It still says "Earned X upvotes for answers..."

Comment: Bronze badge: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/86/status-completed Silver badge: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/47/status-completed Why does the 400 upvote badge have an ID of 47 when the 100 upvote one has an ID of 86? I assume the IDs are created when someone is first awarded a badge. So someone got 400 upvotes before they got 100 upvotes?

Comment: I'm doubtful about this - `Tag scores are only recalculated once daily, at 03:00 UTC`. Today I modified a question in which relevant language tag was missing. The moment I updated (added the language tag) the question my tag score got incremented in the very next moment as I had an answer on that question. The up-votes on my answer on that question got instantly credited towards my tag score. It happened at 00:15 hrs UTC time.

Comment: I think it seems to happen dynamically at the moment, although there seems to be a lag between answers getting upvotes and the score going up

Comment: Do zero score answers count towards the tag answer count?

Comment: The text on the profile should be worded as you did it here! I find "Earn at least 100 total score for at least 20 non-community wiki answers in the python tag" confusing because it could also mean "earn 100+ score on at least 20 answers each"