# Will tag score be re-calculated automatically after deleting negative score answers?

Tags: support, tags, answers, down-votes, tag-badges

I received some negative scores to answers. I didn't want to delete them, as I learned a lot on them and they might be of use for others. (I edited the answer of course, but negative votes remained). I don't care about the lost reputation, but what bothers me a litte is that I lost score on those particular tags, which counts for tag badges.

Will tag score be re-calculated automatically after deleting negative score answers, or is there any other option to get the score back but not delete that negative answer?

Do I need to make a reputation recalc first? (I'd like to avoid that.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Tag score (for the purposes of badging) is recalculated on a daily basis. This allows tag badges to [be revoked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63835/what-are-tag-badges-how-do-they-work/63836#63836) when they are no longer applicable to a user. Since deleted and wiki answers don't count towards these calculations, the answer to your question is yes, deleting the negative score answers would cause your total score to be recalculated automatically.

As far as getting back the tag score goes, my recommendation is to first not worry about it, and then work on providing more higher quality answers in those tags. The decision on whether or not to delete answers should be based on how much value they add to the question, not on how they influence badge progress (which you seem to acknowledge).

Comment: Tim, thanks for thorough answer!

Answer (score 7):

Tag score is unrelated to rep recalcs.

It is cached daily.

Deleting answers or retagging questions will cause the score to update on the next run.

Comment: So if a tag is changed to be a synonym, in 24h everyone that had the badge in the synonym lose it, right? (and perhaps they aquire a bigger badge on the main tag, because now the main tag has more q/a "connected")

Comment: pretty much ... tag badges are revoked if the pre-reqs are not met