# Will tag score of all answerers be re-calculated after re-tagging question?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-badges, tag-score

I know how [tag-badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63835/what-are-tag-badges-how-do-they-work/63836#63836) are awarded. I also know [re-calculation of tag score](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102203/will-tag-score-be-re-calculated-automatically-after-deleting-negative-score-answ) is done after deleting answers with respective tag.

My question: Will re-tagging of a question force re-calculationt of the tag score of every person who had answered the question? (In other words after adding or deleting a tag at any time.)

And one more question I would like to ask (please don't mind). If I had added tag to a question after answering the question, will tag score be re-calculated for all users except me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes retagging of questions will force a recalculate of the tag score.

It might not happen immediately, but it does happen.

It also means that if the retag causes you to no longer qualify for the tag badge, *you will lose the tag badge*.

Comment: If person had tag-score of 100 and got bronze badge, and after recalculation score is gone under 100 then tag badge will be revoked. Is it so?

Comment: @SomnathMuluk - yes. That's what I said

Comment: @SomnathMuluk: While most badges are not revoked if you disqualify (you just don't get credit for the next one), tag badges are an exception; they are revoked immediately upon disqualification. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17853/how-do-badges-work