# How does the tags count in the profile work?

Tags: discussion, tags, profile-page, vote-count, tag-score

I click on my Profile and can see or example total score of 5 in 18 answered questions for the JSP Tag, nice!

Now I click on the tag "JSP" and I can count 9 upvotes!

And the same goes for other tags too.

Am I missing anything?

Comment: The tag counts update at the end of each day (midnight GMT) from memory. That's the only time I see them update. The same goes for ranks/leagues etc. Some rep changes can take a few minutes to kick in as well.

Comment: I didnt answer anything with JSP in the last two weeks... adn didnt got any new Upvotes lately

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102203/will-tag-score-be-re-calculated-automatically-after-deleting-negative-score-answ?lq=1

Comment: @O.D Not sure how it works, but the math seems right - you also have a total of -4 from other answers that have been down-voted.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On second look, it's not related to cache.

True, you got 9 upvotes **[but you also got 4 downvotes](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:395659%20%5Bjsp%5D)**:

> [image]

9 + (-1) + (-1) + (-2) = 5

Q.E.D

Also worth to mention that the tag score title says "total score", not "total upvotes":

> > [image]

Comment: I give up.....!

Comment: @O.D and that means.. ?

Comment: Ur right i didnt c the Downvotes, ill have to check other Tags but until then i accept the Answer.

Comment: OK, fair enough.