# Android Badge earned

Tags: discussion, tags

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [What are tag badges? How do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63835/what-are-tag-badges-how-do-they-work)
>   [List of all badges with full descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions)

I've just received the information that I earned the Android Badge - anyway I couldn't find this badge in the [listing](https://stackoverflow.com/badges). Is there a description available on how this badge is earned and are there more badges which are not described in the [badges list](https://stackoverflow.com/badges)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a tag badge. The full list is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/badges?tab=tags). This lists the requirements for each level of the badge (bronze, silver and gold). You need to get a total score above a threshold **and** provide a certain number of non-community wiki answers to earn the badge.

> - Bronze Tag Badge - You must have a total score of 100 in at least 20 non-community wiki answers to achieve this badge.
> - Silver Tag Badge - You must have a total score of 400 in at least 80 non-community wiki answers to achieve this badge.
> - Gold Tag Badge - You must have a total score of 1000 in at least 200 non-community wiki answers to achieve this badge.

The [android badge](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/291/android) lists all the recipients. Your name is first (at the moment) as you are the latest recipient.

Comment: Beat me to it, was just going to post exactly your answer almost word by word. :)