# Use consistent terms when describing tag badge rules

Tags: feature-request, tag-badges, badge-description

The description of the rules for awarding tag badges as stated on the [badges page](https://stackoverflow.com/badges?tab=tags) seems inconsistent and confusing.

[image: kitty no like-y]

[This mso faq post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63835/what-are-tag-badges-how-do-they-work) states that the metric used is "sum of upvotes - sum of downvotes". However, badge descriptions (and tooltips) use the term *"upvotes"* (which isn't accurate) while the legend on the page use *"total score"* (without explaining what a score means).

#### Suggestions:

- Always use *"total score"* (*"upvotes"* is misleading) when describing the tag badges. E.g.:

  > Achieve a total score of 100 for at least 20 answers in the [.net](/questions/tagged/.net) tag
- Explicitly define what *"total score"* means, perhaps in a tooltip and/or a link in the legend section to the relevant faq.

---

Here's a mockup to speak the thousand words...

[image: mockup]

Comment: A *freehand cat*? I'm still in shock over this innovation. It shall be the new gold standard of Meta illustration.

Comment: Looks like I'm not the only one [misled by the description (upvotes vs score)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/113966/revisions). Converted question to a feature-request.