# How do we know how much up-votes are still needed to get the "C#" tag-badge?

Tags: support, badges, tag-badges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are tag badges? How do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63835/what-are-tag-badges-how-do-they-work)

I've given answers of more than 100 questions about C#, and I got more than 100 up votes for those answers.
Yet, I don't get the tag badge for C#.

How many up-votes still I need to get, to obtain that tag badge?

Comment: Are you sure you have answered more than 100 questions with a total score of more than 100? Where did you see or how did you know this?

Comment: count points!!!!

Comment: What points...?

Comment: upvotes of answers!!!

Comment: @ChrisF: I closed this as a duplicate of that question earlier, but a flag revealed to me that they weren't quite the same so I lifted it.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn This is a duplicate, as the answer to this question is the answer to the other question. As I have seen, a question that is already answered in a question tagged [meta-tag:faq] is usually closed as duplicate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looking at your [profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/200349/), you've currently got a total score (up votes - down votes) of 64 in the C# tag. You get the badge when your total score in the C# tag is at least 100, and you've answered at least 20 questions.

Comment: how do you know that!!!!!

Comment: @sikender There's a score visible in your profile, under **Tags**, but I think this includes votes on questions as well as answers.

Comment: @Jeremy Banks: There's a tooltip on the score that reveals the distribution of scores for non-wiki questions and answers.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn Wow, I never know that. Thanks. I must hover everything.

Comment: @Jeremy Banks: http://i.stack.imgur.com/jxDZ2.png

Comment: +1 for editing *"upvotes"* to *"total score"*. Now I can delete my answer ;)

Answer (score 3):

The score you have for [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) is reported in [your user profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/200349/sikender?tab=tags), right to the left of the tag.

[image: screenshot]

The tooltip reports all the data you need: The score is 64, and you answered 68 non-wiki questions.

To get the bronze badge, your score needs to be 100, and you should answer at least 20 non-wiki questions. While you answered to enough questions to get the badge, your score is still too low.