# Are tags also badges?

Tags: support, tags, badges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do “badges” work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17853/how-do-badges-work)
>   [List of all badges with full descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions)

I was looking at somebody's profile on Stack Overflow, and I saw Java was one of the badges (bronze as well as silver).

I appreciate if anybody could explain how tags work as badges.

Comment: You may also be interested in the [tag-badge-specific answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions/68395#68395) to the "List of all badges with full descriptions" question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All tags have badges - click on the `Badges` button, then `Tags`.

Tags get have bronze, silver and gold badges - awarded to people who got 100, 400 and 1000 upvotes on 20, 80 and 200 non-community wiki answers in the topic.

These badges are called tag specialist badges.

See [How do "badges" work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17853/how-do-badges-work) and [What are tag badges? How do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63835/what-are-tag-badges-how-do-they-work/63836#63836).

Comment: A tag has to have 100 questions before the badges are able to be awarded (see [What are tag badges?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/63836/160551)).