# How to find out what my score is in a specific tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, badges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are tag badges? How do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63835/what-are-tag-badges-how-do-they-work)

Is there any way to find out how many upvotes or points I've got in a specific tag or tags, like php, android, c#, etc? And how many additional points I need to get a specific tag badge?

Similar to when you click on privileges, where it shows the progress in points needed to gain the next privilege.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure you can!  Go to your profile page and click the [`tags` tab](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/172665/alphamale?tab=tags)... You'll see something like this :

[image]

The number on the left of the tag is how many votes you got for that specific tag.

The screenshot is taken from my profile here on meta... But the same applies for SO proper and any SE site for that matter.

Tag badges are awarded when you reach a certain number of votes and posts for a specific tag.  You can see the information about exactly how much is needed from [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/badges?tab=tags)

Comment: and how can i know that how much points is needed to get a specific tag?

Comment: I do not follow what you mean... Are you perhaps talking about [badges that you get for tags](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/80/support?userid=172936)?

Comment: You don't need points to get a tag. You do need points to get a tag *badge*, though, which you can find in the badges page.

Comment: And seriously, Meta is not exempt from the "search first before asking" rule. This stuff has been asked numerous times while the info is just staring right at you.

Comment: Damn, you have the [support] badge. That means you actually help people on meta. My badges ([feature-request] and [discussion]) tell me that I spend way too much time opposing stuff :/

Comment: @man - I like to think I am helping.... Helping myself to some meta rep ;)