# I lost my JavaScript badge

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, badges, tag-badges, revoked-badges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do “badges” work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17853/how-do-badges-work)
>   [What are tag badges? How do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63835/what-are-tag-badges-how-do-they-work)

I earned the JavaScript badge a while ago.

Today, I earned the [jQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery) badge, and I see that there's no `javascript` badge anymore on my profile.

Can I lose it after earning it?

Comment: heres the link: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17853/how-do-badges-work

Comment: Now you should have it. You have 100 score on the [tag:javascript] tag.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you go under a tag badge threshold e.g. 100 votes for the bronze badge, you lose the tag badge. Currently you have 99 votes for the JavaScript tag:

[image: jQuery vs JavaScript badge votes]

Probably some questions where ratagged which you have answered.

Don't worry, +1 vote and you will regain the bronze badge.

Answer (score 14):

You dropped below the threshold for earning that badge (you currently only have 99 answered questions under JavaScript), so the badge was retracted. While most badges are normally never taken away (except for extreme circumstances), tag badges are immediately taken away when you no longer meet the criteria.

From [How do “badges” work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17853/how-do-badges-work):

> ### What can cause a badge to be lost/revoked/taken away after it is awarded?
>
> The Stack Exchange administration has stated repeatedly that "regular" badges never go away unless they were obtained by heinous cheating. Behavior that qualifies as "heinous" is defined by devs on a case-by-case basis, but here are some guidelines:
>
> - using a bunch of sockpuppets to upvote posts by your main account for Enlightened or Nice Question qualifies as "heinous"
> - downvoting something and then immediately undoing your downvote just so you get Critic for free is kinda dumb, but not "heinous"
>
> **Tag badges, on the other hand, disappear immediately if you ever cease to meet their criteria, which could happen through deletion or downvotes.**