# category badge threshholds

Tags: discussion, tags, badges, tag-badges

So if you get 100 upvotes for answers in a particular category you get a bronze badge. eg.

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/86/status-completed

If you get 400 upvotes for answers in a particular category you get a silver badge. eg.

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/47/status-completed

How many to get a gold badge? Are there even gold badge for categories?

Also, why does the 400 upvote badge have an ID of 47 when the 100 upvote one has an ID of 86? I assume the IDs are created when someone is first awarded a badge. So someone got 400 upvotes before they got 100 upvotes?

Comment: Gold badge is 1000 votes and 200 answers.

Comment: [just for showing profs](http://i.stack.imgur.com/FmnNm.png)  what @Mysticial said  or in other word just trolling Mysticial :P

Comment: @NullPonyPointer Hey! Not cool... not cool at all... haha... :)

Comment: There was another part to my question lol. I posted it here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63835/what-are-tag-badges-how-do-they-work#comment515105_63836