# Does deleted answer count towards your tag score?

Tags: support, tags, answers, down-votes

When answering\asking a question (say a Java question) and got downvotes, I want to delete the answer. You know that downvoting a "Java" answer also downvotes the user's "Java" tag. The question is, when I delete the answer, my lost reputation will be restored again. But what about the "Java" tag score, will it be restored also? or still lost?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But what about the "Java" tag score, will it be restored also? or still lost?

It will be restored also. I don't see any reason to not restore it.

From [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/63836/187824):

> posts which are in community wiki status or **that have been deleted *do not* count towards your tag score**.