# Notification for tag badge appears multiple times

Tags: discussion, tags, reputation, badges, notifications

This may be hard to reproduce, or not even a bug, but here it goes:

Recently, I passed 100 reps in the [r](/questions/tagged/r) tag, and earned the corresponding bronze badge. However, a couple hours later, my rep in this tag went below 100 and then above 100. When I passed 100 reps for the second time, I did *not* receive a second badge (as expected); however, I received a *second notification* for earning the [r](/questions/tagged/r) badge.

Is this a bug?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tag badges are the only badges that can be lost (unless your badge is gained wrongfully and is taken away); therefore, when you went below 100 votes you lost the badge. When you reached the 100 votes again, you got the badge back and received the notification again.

You cannot receive each level of the tag badge more than once (ie you can have only one bronze badge for [r](/questions/tagged/r) at a time)). This can be seen in the answer to: [How do "badges" work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17853/how-do-badges-work)

> Tag badges, on the other hand, disappear immediately if you ever cease to meet their criteria, which could happen through deletion or downvotes.

Comment: Funny, this is not very clear in the docs. In the tag badges tab, we se the description for each bronze tag saying "Earned 100 upvotes for at least 20 answers...". Since it's past tense (earned), I thought it could not be lost.

Comment: @Ferdinand.kraft: There is a tag-badge-specific-FAQ on the subject too if you're interested: [What are tag badges and tag score? How do they work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63835/what-are-tag-badges-and-tag-score-how-do-they-work)

Comment: @animuson, thanks for the link. I think this rule should be made clear here (http://stackoverflow.com/badges?tab=tags) also.