# Background color is not working in some badges

Tags: discussion, badges, design

Background color is not working in some badges

Please see this image:

[image]

All badge background colors are black. But the profile-page and specific-question  badge background color was white? Is it a bug?

Comment: Interesting. Exactly the same question just asking "why" instead of stating "it's not working" got 11 upvotes while this got 11 downvotes.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - That's [the difference](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/186936/revisions) between [bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bug) and [support](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/support) tags :)

Comment: @hims056 yup too bad (for the OP) he didn't realize it before. :/

Comment: @hims056 by the way how did you notice my comment?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - While reviewing. Read the whole comment after reading the word "Interesting" :)

Comment: @hims056 lol I always forget there are review queues here on Meta too!

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd . It's fun ?? am soooooooo sad :( !!!! lol

Comment: @RameshRams you sadness is overflowing... :-P

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd kikiki... =D  !!!! OMG Please any one put down vote for this question ....  please please !!!!! :p

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Those are [tag badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63835/what-are-tag-badges-how-do-they-work). They are styled differently because they are different badges.

Comment: Something which you could have found out by just clicking the Badges tab...