# How can we check the completion of tag badges?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-badges

How can we check status of **tag badges**.

I did my research: 
[What are tag badges? How do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63835/what-are-tag-badges-how-do-they-work)

Comment: what status...?

Comment: @Azik similar to **[How unsung am I](http://data.stackexchange.com/ubuntumeta/query/7521/how-unsung-am-i)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just go to [your profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1841054/luv) -> [*Tags* tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1841054/luv?tab=tags) -> [sort by *Votes*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1841054/luv?tab=tags&sort=votes)

Here you can see all your tags score. Which indicates tag badge process.

E.g. You can see you have 200 score in [sql](/questions/tagged/sql). If you hover on it you can see that you have answered 131 non-wiki questions. So to get silver tag badge for [sql](/questions/tagged/sql) you need 200 more score for that. (You have already answered 80+ questions)

> [image]

Comment: I was looking something similar to **[How unsung am I](http://data.stackexchange.com/ubuntumeta/query/7521/how-unsung-am-i)**.

Comment: @Luv don't think there is but we can always write one.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd That would of great help to Stack exchange network users .