# Columns in "top users" list for a given tag

Tags: support, reputation, reputation-leagues

This must have been asked before, but I can't find it.

On [this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/matlab/topusers) page (and similar others), how exactly is the first column (which shows the tip "total score") computed? My question apples to the "answerers" and "askers" sections; and to "last 30 days" / "all time".

For instance: for answerers, last 30 days, the number is too low to correspond to reputation earned in the last 30 days; and too large to be average reputation per day in the last 30 days. So what is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "possible duplicate" to this question requires some reading, specifically reading through the link to one of the duplicates of that question to fully understand, but the value you are referencing is the "tag score".

To quote the [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) on the [tag badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63835/what-are-tag-badges-how-do-they-work) (which is one of the dups to the dup question):

> ## What is this tag score you speak of?
>
> A tag score is basically the combined total of all the upvotes (+1) and downvotes (-1) you've accumulated on answers under that specific tag (votes on questions do not count). As well, posts which are in community wiki status or that have been deleted do not count towards your tag score. Tag scores are only recalculated once daily, at 03:00 UTC.