# When is tag status calculated?

Tags: discussion

I have read this question: [What are tag badges? How do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63835/what-are-tag-badges-how-do-they-work) But I still do not understand, why my Java tag score does not changes. It is currently: 48 Java × 89 for several days, though I replied to two questions meanwhile and my new answers have combined score 4. I thought it will be 52 but it is unchanged. Why?

Comment: Wait more time, someday it'll be updated :)

Comment: I see, thanks for linked question.

Comment: Btw can I find out how old the information is? I am curious if it is few days / weeks / months?

Comment: No, there's not really a way to figure out when your stats were updated, and a global "last update" counter is pretty useless because some profiles do get updated on some of the nightly runs before it fails, while others don't.

Comment: tag was updated today