# High rep user voted to close as duplicate, but question remained open - wondering why?

Tags: support, vote-to-close, duplicate-questions

I'm a relative high rep user (177k) on Stack Overflow. I am accustomed to being able to unilaterally close a question as a duplicate. But, today when I voted to close as a duplicate [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28509650/node-js-and-websocket-concurrent-connections), the question did not close. It just registered one close vote.

Did a policy change? Or is there something different about [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28509650/node-js-and-websocket-concurrent-connections) that keeps it from being subject to the immediate closure as a duplicate?

Comment: Are you aware it's based on having a gold tag badge on one of the tags on the question? It's not reputation based.

Comment: normally when that happens, it's because the original tags when the question was posted did not include any of your dup hammer tags, then the question was edited to include one of your dup hammer tags, but dup hammer only applies for orginal tags. But in this case, none of the tags on the question include a tag that you have a gold tag badge in, thus no dup hammer is possible for you on that question.

Comment: @Roombatron5000 - I forgot the dup hammer was tag-specific, not reputation specific.  Why don't you post that as an answer and I can accept.

Comment: Boy, it wasn't easy for me to find my list of gold tags and even harder to find out how far I am from getting to a gold tag on a particular tag that I don't yet have a gold tag on.  Did finally find the first list.  Never did find out how to see how close I am to a gold tag for a specific tag.

Comment: @jfriend00 You can see that [here](http://stackoverflow.com/users/816620/jfriend00?tab=tags) *make sure sorting by votes not name*. You need at least 1000 score and x 200 (at least 200 non-community wiki answers) So `dom tag` and `css tag` are getting fairly close for your dup hammering!

Comment: @Roombatron5000 - OK, that helps.  That page is a bit confusing.  The counts to the left of the tag turn out to be the upvote counts, not the reputation earned on questions with that tag.  The popup over the number says "total score" which implied reputation to me, but it is a pure upvote count.  The description for gold badge says "You must have a total score of 1000 in at least 200 non-community wiki answers to achieve this badge."  There's that "score" word again.  What does "score" actually mean in this context?  Does it only mean upvotes?  So, it doesn't count accepted answers?

Comment: Yea, score is your upvotes minus downvotes count. Not reputation. http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/63836/244519

Comment: @Roombatron5000 - OK, I guess in stackexchange nomenclature: `score = upvotes - downvotes`.  Didn't know that.  Thx.