# How does the "Next tag badge:" determine the badges to display?

Tags: discussion, tags, badges, profile-page

I was checking out the new profile and was going to go about changing what is displayed for the "Next tag badge:", bellow is all the badges I could select

[image: badge select]

However there is a badge missing, I was fully expecting Fate/Stay Night to appear given what I am shown on my Profile Page

[image: profile page]

As you can see, I have more posts and a higher score on Fate/Stay Night than I do with Fullmetal Alchemist. 
What's more as you can see in the first screenshot I am looking at the All tab for the badges and Naruto, Anime Production and Tropes seems to be taking priority over other tags.

[image: all tags]

As you can see above 3 tags could easily be replaced with 3 others if score was used to determine which tag badges to display, but also in regards to Tropes.

I haven't asked/answer/had my own posts edited in almost a year so the likely hood of me wanting to aim for this bad is very low, unlike Fate/Stay Night in which case the past few days I've answered a few questions (it's almost been a answer a day).

So I am wondering how exactly does the "Next tag badge:" determine which badges I can choose to display?
 or is this a bug?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/68395/279180) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/63836/279180):

> A tag must appear on a minimum of 100 questions to be considered for tag badges.

There are no fate-stay-night badges yet, since there are only 53 questions.

Comment: So in other words even if i did qualify for a badge for fate-stay-night i wouldn't get it because it doesn't appear on at least 100 questions and that's why it wont appear in the Next tag badge section?

Comment: @Memor-X I think yes.

Comment: This is especially common on small Meta sites; sometimes [discussion] is the only available one, sometimes you can't even track a single one.