# New profile - select your next TAG badge to track

Tags: feature-request

Minor usabality suggestion, when clicking the next tag badge to track (under reputation):

Change the title here to **"Select your next tag badge"**

Because I was wondering why I couldn't track one of the unearned badges, by typing it into this box.  I thought it was a bug, and it wasn't until I closed the dialog that I noticed there was another section off to the right on the new profile, for tracking the non-tag badges separately.

[image]

Comment: How do you get to this screen? I came here to feature-request a screen like this where I can see my progress towards tag badges - I've looked everywhere for it! There's no link to it  under "reputation" on my profile screen.

Comment: Huh, "found it", apparently this page is hidden for everyone below 20,000 rep, and it's a secret or something, SE people don't care to comment on it - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/254052/cant-track-tag-badges-without-20k-rep

Answer (score 5):

Its already a thing, after a fashion -if nothing else, the path to find that page is rather hard to find if you're not explicitly looking for tag badges.

[image: Partial screenshot of profile page showing that you can pick what to track for a low rep user]

For users who haven't maxed out their privileges, you can track a tag badge instead of the next privilege

For high rep users this is by default

[image: Partial screenshot of the same for a high rep user]

Both will let you pick what tag to keep track of if you click on the cog-wheel next to the "next tag badge". Regular badges are off to the right.

[image: screenshot of tag selection page]