# Clicking on "track a tag badge instead" removes tracking controls

Tags: bug, tags, badges, tracking

Today I went to my profile on Open Source beta and clicked on "track a tag badge instead" option in the leftmost frame. Since this moment, the section doesn't show any controls whatsoever:

[image]

I observed the same behavior on another beta site (Arduino). On all sites which are not in beta tracking for tag badges seems to work fine. I suppose I should report it here instead of doing so on every beta site.

Edit: there is a [related question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/264286/how-to-revert-track-tag-badge-instead) where the OP didn't have any tags to track before he clicked, which is not my case. Also, that question has no answers.

Comment: Do you have any activity on these sites? Any tags you have been active on (before clicking the track a tag badge instead" option)?

Comment: Yes, I have 90 rep points on [gpl] tag for [this answer](http://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/1877/are-pirated-gpl-derived-premium-themes-legal/1883#1883)