# How can moderators track badge progress of tags?

Tags: feature-request, tags, badges, profile-page

Tag progress bars look like this for regular users of a site:

> [image]

However, that part of the profile page is empty for moderators. [Maybe cause one can choose between tracking privileges and tracking tag progress, and mods all the available privileges].

I find the tag progress a nice gamification feature. So, **wanted to know if tag progress feature would be available to the mods too sometime in the future?**  If not, then would it be a good idea to have?

Comment: I've still got the tag badge tracker: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cLxQ4.png

Comment: @Cai Weird. I don't have it in mine: http://imgur.com/a/ViTTh .  Bug?  [Public Beta site]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The tag badge tracker *isn't* disabled for moderators. It just happens to be the case that the site you moderate ([DevOps](https://devops.stackexchange.com/)) has no tags eligible for tag badges.

[*What are tag badges?*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/63836/336144) states

> A tag must appear on a minimum of 100 questions to be considered for tag badges.

The most popular tag on DevOps, [jenkins](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jenkins), has [86 questions as of writing](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jenkins). Hence, there are no tags that can give tag badges, and the tracker is disabled. Once the tag passes 100 questions, it should be enabled for tracking as expected.

Comment: as a mod, I totally track badges on the site I'm a moderator on.