# How did I just receive a tag badge if there were no recent upvotes on that tag and no edits to add that tag to prior answers?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tags, tag-badges

Yesterday (14 October) in [Music: Practice and Theory](https://music.stackexchange.com/) I received the bronze [`modulation`](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/modulation) tag badge. Yet a look at my [reputation](https://music.stackexchange.com/users/21766/richard?tab=reputation) shows that I haven't received any upvotes on answers for `modulation`-tagged questions since 20 September.

Furthermore, there have been no edits on questions that I've answered that retroactively add the `modulation` tag.

How did I receive this tag badge?

Comment: A user was removed on 2 October (-10 points), but that's the only such action. No anomalous increase of 2 points.

Comment: @ErikA I'm exclusively discussing my answers; in an effort to de-clutter the post I made that unclear. Sorry! And yes, I'm accounting for any tag edits, none of which have occurred in the past several days.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can only receive tag badges for tags which are used on [100 or more questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/63836/295232).

[Modulation from D major to D minor, should I go sudden or gradual?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/90643/modulation-from-d-major-to-d-minor-should-i-go-sudden-or-gradual) was the 100th such question, asked two days ago, and this event made the [modulation] tag eligible for tag badges. Those are usually awarded somewhere in the early UTC morning, that job runs once a day.