# Tag badges aren't awarded if there is already a regular badge with the same name

Tags: bug, badges, tag-badges

On Meta Stack Exchange, we have an [editor](/questions/tagged/editor) tag with (currently) 440 questions, more than the [minimum of 100](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/63836/295232) for tag badges to be awarded. We also have [two users, balpha and Jeff Atwood](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/editor/topusers) who have a score of more than 100 and more than 20 answers, so they qualify for the bronze tag badge. Yet, they don't have them:

- [balpha's badges, A–L](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/115866/balpha?tab=badges&sort=name)
- [Jeff Atwood's badges, A–E](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/1/jeff-atwood?tab=badges&sort=name&page=1)
- [Jeff Atwood's badges, E–P](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/1/jeff-atwood?tab=badges&sort=name&page=2)

I *suspect* this is because they already have another [bronze Editor badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/3). The tag badges don't exist in SEDE either, so it's not a display issue.

Comment: If this is an intentional feature, while this may have made sense back when it was implemented, it doesn't make sense now, as users can end up deprived of a privilege simply because there exists a non-tag badge with the same name as a tag for which they'd qualify for a gold badge.

Comment: @Rob https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/1172810 (that's how I found this case). Looks like VonC is missing an editor tag badge too: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/editor/topusers

Comment: [On SO](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1172810#resultSets) hundreds [**lost** the "editor" tag badge](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5beditor%5d&mixed=1), there's not enough votes to affect the [beta tag badge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/beta) or [pundit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pundit?tab=Votes), etc.

Comment: @Rob I think it's only VonC, you need 20 answers to qualify for the tag badge, and he's the only one in the top users list with that much answers.

Comment: Good point!, multiple constraints. For editor it says [984 editor × 45](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6309/vonc?tab=tags&sort=name&page=19), but for the [badges page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6309/vonc?tab=badges&sort=name&page=3) it simply shows a ***single*** regular bronze "editor" badge; instead of two badges for "editor". Greg should ask [7 more](https://stackoverflow.com/users/893/greg-hewgill?tab=tags&sort=name&page=12) for the badge he won't get. ;)